# Rails SQLite vs MySQL Booleans

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm working with Rails 3.2.   My development box is using SQLite3 and my production host is using MySQL.   Rails SQLite ActiveRecord connector will not save booleans as 1 or 0 and will only save it as 't' or 'f'.  Of course I want DB neutral code but I cannot find any way around the following.  I have a user model and a shift model.   In this query I need all the shifts (work schedules) and I need to order the results by the related table as well as apply the boolean conditions.

```
 @sh=  Shift.find(:all, :include=>:user, :order=>'users.rating DESC', :conditions=>["a1=1 or a1='t'"])
```

I have also learned about ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quoted_true and quoted_false.  I suspect I could change them but that also seems non portable and would probably be silently overridden if I upgrade.

I don't want to test for both 1 and 't' (or 0 and 'f').   Is there any way around doing this besides changing my dev environment to mysql?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass the following as a conditions:

```
:conditions => [["a1 = ?", true]]
```